# android spinner not displaying when click

Tags: java, android, filter, spinner, android-spinner

Hi guys i'm doing a program where it has a filter spinner where the spinner will dropdown and show type of filter but now the spinner is not displaying anything. could you guys help me out? I cant seem to find the problem with the code........

here is the java

```
public class SpinnerInfo extends MainProduct {
Spinner spinners;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    spinners = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnertype);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.type_arrays, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinners.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinners.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String [] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.type_arrays);
            String type = dataArray[position];}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
}}
```

the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:elevation="1dp"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:text="Product List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Select Type:"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinnertype"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve the Qn by moving the code to my main.